# Visual Studio 2008 Error

Tags: visual-studio-2008

When I try to open .mdf file in visual studio I get this error message

> User does not have permission to perform this action.

I'm trying to open the database file for the .NET TimeTracker Starter Kit.

I can open the file at home but I can't open it on my work computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help?

http://web.archive.org/web/20080618154412/http://blogs.msdn.com/kaelr/archive/2005/10/28/486369.aspx